# Hilbert calculi for First-Order Logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, proof-theory, hilbert-calculus

I'm a bit confused about the Hilbert-style axiomatization of first-order logic. More precisely, I am a bit confused about completeness w.r.t. to Hilbert-calculi. A complete Hilbert-style calculus I am familiar with uses e.g. the quantifier rule

$$\frac{\phi\rightarrow\psi}{\phi\rightarrow\forall x\psi}$$

for $x$ not free in $\phi$. Now, if we allow for derivations using assumptions, we get that

$$\{\phi(x)\}\vdash\forall x\phi(x)$$

but clearly $\{\phi(x)\}\not\models\forall x\phi(x)$ where $\models$ is classical semantical entailment. That means that the above rule is not sound for derivations with assumptions using open formulae.

Now, in some literature I have read, they avoid this by only showing soundness and completeness w.r.t. to sets of closed formulae, which I dislike as I was taught first-order logic using sequent calculi, where this restriction is not necessary as we can include requirements for the assumptions of the proof in the rule, e.g. by considering the rule

$$\frac{\Gamma\Rightarrow\phi\rightarrow\psi}{\Gamma\Rightarrow\phi\rightarrow\forall x\psi}$$

for $x$ not free in $\Gamma$ and $\phi$.

This leads me to the question:

> Is the restriction to closed formulae (in assumptions) an inherent
>   limitation of the Hilbert-style approach to first-order proof theory or can this be circumvented?

Comment: You can see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576172/elliott-mendelson-introduction-to-mathematical-logic-fourth-edition-definit) as well as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580796/elliott-mendelson-introduction-to-mathematical-logic-fourth-edition-gen-rul).

Comment: See also [Definition of Semantic Entailment in First-order Theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3267656/definition-of-semantic-entailment-in-first-order-theory).

Comment: The issue is that Gen rule is unsound, unless you implicitly assume that $A(x)$ means : "an $x$ whatever is $A$". In order to track at the syntactic level the "whatever" proviso,  the condition "$x$ not free in the assumption/antecedent" is needed.

Comment: At the semantical level, in order to restore the "symmetry" between $\vdash$ and $\vDash$ (symmetry lost in Mendelson's system) the two basic approach are : Enderton's one vs van Dalen's one, i.e. to restrict the meaning of $\vDash$ to *sentences* (closed formulas).